# First boot fails after every shutdown, which also resets the BIOS

Tags: boot, windows, uefi

I recently replaced my motherboard and CPU in my computer, and have noticed a significant issue with my motherboard. Every time I shut down my computer, powering it back on results in boot failure. Specifically, the computer will shut itself down while it is booting into any OS. Afterwards, it reboots and resets the current BIOS configuration to the default settings, and is only then able to boot into the current OS. I have found that this does not happen if I simply restart the computer; it will be able to successfully boot without resetting the BIOS.

(Note: This issue also still occurs even if I don't change any BIOS settings.)

At first I suspected that the CMOS battery may have been dead, but after replacing it, the issue persisted. I have also tested each stick of RAM in my system to make sure they weren't the cause of the issue, to no avail. I also highly doubt that this issue could be caused by bad cooling, as even running high-stress performance tests on my hardware does not cause it to shut down.

The only other thing I could think of was to disable fast boot in Windows, but this ultimately had no effect for me.

PC Specs:

CPU: Ryzen 5 2600 >> Ryzen 5 5600x

GPU: MSI Radeon RX 6600 XT MECH 2X OC

Mobo: Gigabyte B450 Aorus M >> Gigabyte B550 Gaming X V2

PSU: EVGA 550w BR

RAM: TEAMGROUP T-Force Vulcan Z (32GB 3200MHz)

Comment: there may be an option jumper that is configured incorrectly

Comment: Do you mean I may have wired something incorrectly on the motherboard?

Comment: some system boards have jumpers for selecting options .. maybe you have one set to clear CMOS at powerup ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mobo+jumpers&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Take the motherboard out and double check that all the screw inserts for the mobo are lined up correctly with the fixing holes. If one of the inserts is incorrect then it may be creating a short to earth causing the bios issue

Comment: I can confirm there is nothing connecting the clear CMOS jumper on my motherboard. I have also checked all of the screw inserts, and haven't found any issues there.

Comment: Did you check the BIOS settings to see if any overclock settings are set? Boards have been using overclock settings in the "Auto"  configuration. This might be causing the settings to fail causing the BIOS to reset itself.

Comment: might be a dead thread resurrected, but this sounds like the OP is physically pulling power (e.g. a switch on the psu or a switch on a plug strip) and then the motherboard is doing what is sometimes called a "double POST boot". This is usually not normal, but it happens and MB BIOS updates often are supplied by MFG to fix the behavior. I have seen some enthusiasts claim this is normal behavior for specific boards.

Comment: see, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_boot

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is a bad ram. I recently ran into an issue where BIOS kept warning me that might BIOS settings failed. This would happen on every cold boot, but not on reboot. I replaced the ram stick and stopped having this problem. If anyone has this particular problem, use MemtestX86 to test the Ram to be sure.